# How to change Ubuntu's default login screen for gnome ubuntu login screen?

Tags: unity, lightdm

I'm using 14.04 LTS with unity, but i removed the ubuntu desktop and installed the gnome ubuntu desktop instead, since unity has given me some errors... The thing is, im happy with gnome, but the login / lock screen is the one from ubuntu and not gnome. During the installation, i was questioned if I wanted gdm or light dm, I choose the light dm, is it the problem? was i supposed to choose gmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run any one of the following commands -

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Select the display manager you want to use by default and hit enter. Then, restart your computer.

Comment: that's what i did lol, dpkg-reconfigure gdm and switched to gdm instead of lightdm, I cna now lock the screen and I have gnome's login screen! thanks anyway